# Out of memory GL error - Open GL

Tags: android, exception, opengl-es, realm

Android app crashes due to Open GL issue, I had a look at the logs but could not find much information. could you shed some light on why this might be causing please.

This happens when I close the app from the background, not at all sure what might be causing this. One recent change was to do with Realm database. closing it on OnDestroy on the base fragment.

```
  public static void closeRealm() {
        try{
            if (realmInstance != null && !realmInstance.isClosed()) {
                realmInstance.close();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (getPresenter() != null) {
            getPresenter().onDestroy();
        }
        closeRealm();
    }
```

Not sure if above code has anything to do with the error happening.

Thank you for your valuable suggestions in advance
R

```
04-03 15:57:00.541 3132-5748/? E/Exynos_OSAL_Android: [Exynos_OSAL_LockMetaData]: Failed to Exynos_OSAL_GetInfoFromMetaData (err:0x80001005)
04-03 15:57:00.542 3132-5746/? E/Exynos_OSAL_Android: [Exynos_OSAL_UnlockMetaData]: Failed to Exynos_OSAL_GetInfoFromMetaData (err:0x80001005)
04-03 15:57:00.556 3132-7193/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [GraphicBufferSource] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
04-03 15:57:00.558 4203-4266/com.XXXX.onboarding.t3st.dev E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
04-03 15:57:02.528 3132-3132/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(c3c0394:Exynos.AVC.Encoder, ConfigAndroidIntraRefresh(0x6f60000a)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
04-03 15:57:02.983 4550-4550/? E/NFC: isAndroidBeamAllowed - Begin
04-03 15:57:04.212 3132-5875/? E/Exynos_OSAL_Android: [Exynos_OSAL_LockMetaData]: Failed to Exynos_OSAL_GetInfoFromMetaData (err:0x80001005)
04-03 15:57:04.213 3132-5873/? E/Exynos_OSAL_Android: [Exynos_OSAL_UnlockMetaData]: Failed to Exynos_OSAL_GetInfoFromMetaData (err:0x80001005)
04-03 15:57:05.270 3132-3132/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(c3c0397:Exynos.AVC.Encoder, ConfigAndroidIntraRefresh(0x6f60000a)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
04-03 15:57:05.647 4550-4550/? E/NFC: isAndroidBeamAllowed - Begin
04-03 15:57:06.296 3132-6005/? E/Exynos_OSAL_Android: [Exynos_OSAL_LockMetaData]: Failed to Exynos_OSAL_GetInfoFromMetaData (err:0x80001005)
04-03 15:57:06.298 3132-6003/? E/Exynos_OSAL_Android: [Exynos_OSAL_UnlockMetaData]: Failed to Exynos_OSAL_GetInfoFromMetaData (err:0x80001005)
04-03 15:57:08.187 3132-7193/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(c3c039a:Exynos.AVC.Encoder, ConfigAndroidIntraRefresh(0x6f60000a)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
04-03 15:57:08.549 4550-4550/? E/NFC: isAndroidBeamAllowed - Begin
04-03 15:57:08.948 5343-5411/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 1 size : 0Kb duration : 5ms lastUpdatedAfter : 22780 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 199
04-03 15:57:09.871 3132-6205/? E/Exynos_OSAL_Android: [Exynos_OSAL_LockMetaData]: Failed to Exynos_OSAL_GetInfoFromMetaData (err:0x80001005)
04-03 15:57:09.873 3132-6203/? E/Exynos_OSAL_Android: [Exynos_OSAL_UnlockMetaData]: Failed to Exynos_OSAL_GetInfoFromMetaData (err:0x80001005)
04-03 15:57:10.955 3132-27681/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(c3c039d:Exynos.AVC.Encoder, ConfigAndroidIntraRefresh(0x6f60000a)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
04-03 15:57:11.205 5343-5411/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 1 size : 1Kb duration : 3ms lastUpdatedAfter : 2257 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2200 mCurrentSize : 847
04-03 15:57:14.099 20342-6380/? E/SKBD: updateShiftState() : 2
04-03 15:57:18.022 3643-4817/? E/InputMethodManagerService: Perflock object null
04-03 15:57:18.129 20342-20342/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: getInstance start
04-03 15:57:18.129 20342-20342/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: sendSIPInformation state:6  isAbstractKeyboardView : true
04-03 15:57:18.130 20342-6395/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: sending null keyboardInfo as SIP is closed
04-03 15:57:26.151 4682-21915/? E/WakeLock: release without a matched acquire!
04-03 15:57:29.276 3643-4317/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1724 [2018-04-03 15:57:29.276]
04-03 15:57:35.439 1802-1802/? E/vxv: Sync is not initialized yet
04-03 15:57:38.108 5343-5411/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 1 size : 0Kb duration : 8ms lastUpdatedAfter : 26903 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 265
04-03 15:57:40.918 20342-6447/? E/SKBD: updateShiftState() : 2
04-03 15:57:42.121 5343-5411/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 1 size : 5Kb duration : 4ms lastUpdatedAfter : 4012 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 2572
04-03 15:57:44.996 3643-15411/? E/InputMethodManagerService: Perflock object null
04-03 15:57:45.118 20342-20342/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: getInstance start
04-03 15:57:45.118 20342-20342/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: sendSIPInformation state:6  isAbstractKeyboardView : true
04-03 15:57:45.119 20342-6459/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: sending null keyboardInfo as SIP is closed
04-03 15:57:52.650 3132-6369/? E/Exynos_OSAL_Android: [Exynos_OSAL_LockMetaData]: Failed to Exynos_OSAL_GetInfoFromMetaData (err:0x80001005)
04-03 15:57:52.651 3132-6367/? E/Exynos_OSAL_Android: [Exynos_OSAL_UnlockMetaData]: Failed to Exynos_OSAL_GetInfoFromMetaData (err:0x80001005)
04-03 15:57:52.660 3132-7193/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [GraphicBufferSource] query: BufferQueue has been abandoned
04-03 15:57:52.660 3132-3399/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [GraphicBufferSource] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned

                                                      [ 04-03 15:57:52.660  4203: 4266 D/         ]
                                                      NULL == surf->write_back_color_buffer
04-03 15:57:52.661 4203-4266/com.XXXX.onboarding.t3st.dev E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  Out of memory!
04-03 15:57:52.661 4203-4266/com.XXXX.onboarding.t3st.dev A/OpenGLRenderer: GL errors! frameworks/base/libs/hwui/renderthread/CanvasContext.cpp:544
04-03 15:57:53.594 3643-3881/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=569, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
04-03 15:57:55.949 3643-8079/? E/ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked: pendingOptions.getStartX()=39pendingOptions.getStartY()=748
04-03 15:57:59.284 3643-4317/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1725 [2018-04-03 15:57:59.284]
04-03 15:58:00.171 4203-4266/com.XXXX.onboarding.t3st.dev A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4266 (RenderThread)

                                                                   [ 04-03 15:58:00.173  3014: 3014 W/         ]
                                                                   debuggerd: handling request: pid=4203 uid=10898 gid=10898 tid=4266
04-03 15:58:00.210 3021-3021/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1522767480.198:4817): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=6496 comm="debuggerd64" name="com.XXXX.onboarding.t3st.dev" dev="sda18" ino=592295 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0009
04-03 15:58:00.293 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-03 15:58:00.293 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/zerofltexx/zeroflte:7.0/NRD90M/G920FXXS5ERB6:user/release-keys'
04-03 15:58:00.294 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '11'
04-03 15:58:00.294 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
04-03 15:58:00.294 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG: pid: 4203, tid: 4266, name: RenderThread  >>> com.XXXX.onboarding.t3st.dev <<<
04-03 15:58:00.294 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
04-03 15:58:00.298 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'GL errors! frameworks/base/libs/hwui/renderthread/CanvasContext.cpp:544'
04-03 15:58:00.298 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   00000000000010aa  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
04-03 15:58:00.298 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000021  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000007157f08000  x7   0000000000000000
04-03 15:58:00.298 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000083  x9   ffffffffffffffdf  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000001
04-03 15:58:00.298 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     x12  ffffffffffffffff  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000000000000000  x15  0027705a72104fa6
04-03 15:58:00.298 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     x16  00000071554c9ee0  x17  00000071554735ac  x18  000000000000f000  x19  0000007132be14f8
04-03 15:58:00.298 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000000000000006  x21  0000007132be1450  x22  000000000000000b  x23  00000071552d8030
04-03 15:58:00.298 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     x24  00000071422899a0  x25  00000071537d2b20  x26  000000712f2d8400  x27  00000071537d2b38
04-03 15:58:00.298 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     x28  7fffffffffffffff  x29  0000007132be06a0  x30  0000007155470a54
04-03 15:58:00.298 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007132be0680  pc   00000071554735b4  pstate 0000000060000000
04-03 15:58:00.311 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
04-03 15:58:00.312 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000006b5b4  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
04-03 15:58:00.312 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000068a50  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)
04-03 15:58:00.312 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0000000000023f68  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+24)
04-03 15:58:00.312 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000001c9ec  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+52)
04-03 15:58:00.312 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00000000000112ec  /system/lib64/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+232)
04-03 15:58:00.312 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0000000000033e18  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
04-03 15:58:00.312 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000000000003454c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
04-03 15:58:00.312 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000000000003b980  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread22dispatchFrameCallbacksEv+212)
04-03 15:58:00.312 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 000000000003bb5c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+148)
04-03 15:58:00.312 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000000000012488  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+272)
04-03 15:58:00.312 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00000000000a4d40  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+116)
04-03 15:58:00.312 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0000000000068258  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+196)
04-03 15:58:00.312 6496-6496/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000000000001dc00  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
04-03 15:58:11.356 5343-5411/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 1 size : 1Kb duration : 4ms lastUpdatedAfter : 29235 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 831
```

Update:

```
04-03 16:28:00.536 3643-4317/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1785 [2018-04-03 16:28:00.536]
04-03 16:28:03.436 3132-14783/? E/Exynos_OSAL_Android: [Exynos_OSAL_LockMetaData]: Failed to Exynos_OSAL_GetInfoFromMetaData (err:0x80001005)
04-03 16:28:03.438 3132-14781/? E/Exynos_OSAL_Android: [Exynos_OSAL_UnlockMetaData]: Failed to Exynos_OSAL_GetInfoFromMetaData (err:0x80001005)
04-03 16:28:03.442 3132-27681/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [GraphicBufferSource] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned

                                                       [ 04-03 16:28:03.443 13937:14023 D/         ]
                                                       NULL == surf->write_back_color_buffer
04-03 16:28:03.443 13937-14023/com.dopay.onboarding.t3st.dev E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  Out of memory!
04-03 16:28:03.443 13937-14023/com.dopay.onboarding.t3st.dev A/OpenGLRenderer: GL errors! frameworks/base/libs/hwui/renderthread/CanvasContext.cpp:544
04-03 16:28:04.585 13937-14023/com.dopay.onboarding.t3st.dev A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 14023 (RenderThread)

                                                                     [ 04-03 16:28:04.588  3014: 3014 W/         ]
                                                                     debuggerd: handling request: pid=13937 uid=10899 gid=10899 tid=14023
04-03 16:28:04.638 3021-3021/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1522769284.630:4900): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=15233 comm="debuggerd64" name="com.dopay.onboarding.t3st.dev" dev="sda18" ino=592336 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0009
04-03 16:28:04.733 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-03 16:28:04.733 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/zerofltexx/zeroflte:7.0/NRD90M/G920FXXS5ERB6:user/release-keys'
04-03 16:28:04.733 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '11'
04-03 16:28:04.733 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
04-03 16:28:04.733 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG: pid: 13937, tid: 14023, name: RenderThread  >>> com.dopay.onboarding.t3st.dev <<<
04-03 16:28:04.733 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
04-03 16:28:04.736 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'GL errors! frameworks/base/libs/hwui/renderthread/CanvasContext.cpp:544'
04-03 16:28:04.737 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   00000000000036c7  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
04-03 16:28:04.737 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000021  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000007157f08000  x7   0000000000000000
04-03 16:28:04.737 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000083  x9   ffffffffffffffdf  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000001
04-03 16:28:04.737 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     x12  ffffffffffffffff  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000000000000000  x15  001a73dc89945398
04-03 16:28:04.737 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     x16  00000071554c9ee0  x17  00000071554735ac  x18  000000000000f000  x19  0000007132bf54f8
04-03 16:28:04.737 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000000000000006  x21  0000007132bf5450  x22  000000000000000b  x23  00000071552d8030
04-03 16:28:04.737 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     x24  000000714228ac80  x25  00000071537d2960  x26  000000711b5fd120  x27  00000071537d2978
04-03 16:28:04.737 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     x28  7fffffffffffffff  x29  0000007132bf46a0  x30  0000007155470a54
04-03 16:28:04.737 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007132bf4680  pc   00000071554735b4  pstate 0000000060000000
04-03 16:28:04.764 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
04-03 16:28:04.764 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000006b5b4  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
04-03 16:28:04.764 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000068a50  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)
04-03 16:28:04.764 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0000000000023f68  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+24)
04-03 16:28:04.764 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000001c9ec  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+52)
04-03 16:28:04.764 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00000000000112ec  /system/lib64/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+232)
04-03 16:28:04.764 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0000000000033e18  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
04-03 16:28:04.765 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000000000003454c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
04-03 16:28:04.765 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000000000003b980  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread22dispatchFrameCallbacksEv+212)
04-03 16:28:04.765 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 000000000003bb5c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+148)
04-03 16:28:04.765 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000000000012488  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+272)
04-03 16:28:04.765 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00000000000a4d40  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+116)
04-03 16:28:04.765 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0000000000068258  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+196)
04-03 16:28:04.765 15233-15233/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000000000001dc00  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
04-03 16:28:05.192 3643-4781/? E/ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked: pendingOptions.getStartX()=39pendingOptions.getStartY()=748
04-03 16:28:12.736 15280-15280/? E/Zygote: v2
04-03 16:28:12.740 15280-15280/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-03 16:28:15.891 5343-5411/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 1 size : 1Kb duration : 7ms lastUpdatedAfter : 41811 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 831
04-03 16:28:30.490 14455-14615/? E/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: callback not found for RELEASED message
04-03 16:28:30.544 3643-4317/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1786 [2018-04-03 16:28:30.544]
04-03 16:28:47.265 15322-15322/? E/Zygote: v2
04-03 16:28:47.269 15322-15322/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-03 16:28:47.657 15348-15348/? E/Zygote: v2
04-03 16:28:47.662 15348-15348/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
0
```

Comment: Any chance that you are updating views via `RealmChangeListener` in an adapter even after `onDestroy()`?

Comment: Hi @EpicPandaForce you mean in recyclerview adapter? adapter does not have any onDestroy() right. and onDestroy is only in baseFragment and the code which i mentioned.

Comment: You might want to try calling `results.removeAllChangeListeners()` in `onDestroyView()` of the Fragment.

Comment: Should I be doing that on every fragment ? and what would be results.

Comment: or you mean where ever I am using RealmChangeListener  i should use 'results.removeAllChangeListeners()' in  onDestroyView()

Comment: You could try that and see if it helps with this crash or not

Comment: yes doing that now. thank you for that. will update you once i test it

Comment: Unfortunately it still crashes and i have updated the question with the Log data. can you make out anything from this.

Comment: I have that same crash in my app. Did u find what was causing this crash?

Comment: hello @appLogic after couple of tests, what I found was this crash was only happening on my Samsung S6 device. and not on any other device. It might be some memory issues on my device. thing you can try is other devices and see if it occurs. if it occurs on other devices then its the code or else it is the device. the reason I came to this conclusion was. On my app I have Crash report analysis using Instabug and Appsee and when my app crashes on my phone, there are no crash reports generated. hope it helps.